# Where can I get Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS version 15?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have an SSIS project (dtproj) that opens fine in VS 2017 and I am trying to open it in Visual Studio 2019. I installed the "SQL Server Integration Services Projects" extension and have SSDT installed also. When I open the solution it tells me the project is incompatible. If I reload the project I get a message that says, `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version 15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified`.

It makes sense because when I look in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS` I have versions 11, 12, 13, and 14. But not 15. What do I need to install to get version 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will be helpful for others. I fixed this error by installing the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2017, since it contains the Version 15 of ManagedDTS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-visual-studio-vs-2017

I then restarted Visual Studio 2019 and opened the SSIS project fine.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try and fingers crossed it will work.