# Problem with install Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS version 15

Tags: sql, sql-server-data-tools

I need to prepare a server with Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS version 15.
I have installed all packages and extensions related (Analysis Services, Integration Services, Reporting Services) to SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), but I still don't have version 15 version at the path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.
Could you have any idea what I can do more?

Comment: 15 is SSDT for VS 2017 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-ver15 also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65795674/where-can-i-get-microsoft-sqlserver-manageddts-version-15

Comment: Thanks for your answer but,  I have seen the article and It didn't help, so I'm looking another solution.

Comment: I have installed below programs/ extensions,

OLE DB Driver for SQL Server 18.5.0.0
SQL Server 2016 LocalDB 13.1.4001.0
SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017 15.9.45
SQL Server Integration Services Projects 15.0.2000.180
SQL Server Management Studio - 18.11.1 15.0.18410.0
System CLR Types for SQL Server 2019 CTP2.2 15.0.1200.24
Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2017 15.0.27520
Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019 16.0.31110
Visual Studio Professional 2019 16.11.11

but I still don't have the v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll